# Error with serialized file: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have a very strange issue that is completely baffling me.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have a save file which I am writing out with the following code:

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(SavePath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            BinaryFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(fs, SaveData);
        }
```

For most users this is working fine, and it is always working perfectly well for me.  But for less than 1% of my users, this code is writing out a file with only zeros in it.  It has the exact same file size, the file is just full of zeros instead of the actual data from the class.  The class exists in memory, there are no Databases or internet connections involved.

The issue consistently happens for these users, but never for any of the others.  Everyone is running exactly the same code.  Has anyone got any ideas what could cause this to happen?  There must be something specific about these users computers that is causing this to consistently fail.

The file save location is in:
C:\Users[USERNAME]\AppData\LocalLow\ProgramFolder

Comment: File filled with zeroes? Very common thing for all kind of power shortages, antiviruses and caches. Error is irrelevant, since you know content is wrong. You can implement backup strategy, e.g. renaming previous successfully deserialized files into `bak` before saving new ones. Another improvement is to serialize into tmp-file and quickly rename after.

Comment: I hadn't considered that Antivirus might be causing this.  That would at least make some sense, based on how it is affecting some users consistently and others not at all.  Many of the users affected are new users so there are no successfully serialized files for them, but writing it temp and renaming it might work.  Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What about version of Net?  The serialize method can change in different version of Net.  Microsoft doesn't care about forward backward compatibility of users software and often change defaults inside Net with new releases. I've seen this before with binary serialization.  Also users if they modify the object they are serializing cannot deserialize after the object size/properties have changed.

Comment: I will check the .NET versions for the affected users too, but the correct redistributable should be installed as a prerequisite for my application.